# How do I search for a structure by name?

Tags: screeps

I just started and am trying to search for a structure by name. I've been looking through the API with no luck. I can't seem to find the name property on any structure objects, so I can't just loop through them all and find the one I want.

How can I search for a structure by name? Is there an accessible name property somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

In most cases searching by id or type is more preferable as only Spawns have legit names.

In case of id

```
var someStructure = Game.getObjectById('....');
```

In case of structure type, e.g. looking for extensions

```
var extensions = Game.rooms.W25S25.find(FIND_STRUCTURES, {filter:{structureType: STRUCTURE_EXTENSION}});
```

A filter part of the find can also be more sophisticated, e.g. looking for structures not filled with energy.

```
{ filter: (s) => ((
            s.structureType == STRUCTURE_SPAWN
            || s.structureType == STRUCTURE_EXTENSION
            || s.structureType == STRUCTURE_TOWER
            ) && (s.energy < s.energyCapacity)
        )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most structures don't have names, the exception being spawns.
See [this article](http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/205990342-StructureSpawn) for more information.

Those are already in a seperate hash, `Game.spawns`.

You could go with:

```
for(name in Game.spawns){console.log("Found spawn " + Game.spawns[name]");}
```

If you are looking for another structure type, all structures have an `id` property.